# Calculating the angles of vectors

Tags: vectors

If I have two vectors, say:

[100] and [101]

and I want to calculate two angles between them, uniformly distributed, would it just be:

[1 0 0.33] and [1 0 0.66]?

So,

[100] = 0 degrees
[101] = 45 degrees

Does this mean that:

[1 0 0.33] = 15 degrees?

and

[1 0 0.66] = 30 degrees?

Comment: If I understand your question, no.  For example, if the angle from a spot on the ground to the top of a flagpole is 45 degrees, the angle to a line one third of the way up is not 15 degrees.

Comment: Why not? 1/3*45 =15

Comment: Imagine standing back from a wall with a laser pointer and slowly rotating.  in the beginning, a degree of rotation only moves the dot a little bit.  but as it moves down the wall, eventually, just a small rotation will move the dot way down the line.  So as you can see, there is not a linear relationship between angle and the distance.

Comment: What is the best way to define 2 evenly spaced angles between these two vectors? By angle, or by the height they would move up?

Comment: By angle is best.  IMO.  But I suppose it depends on the context.

Comment: So how do I calculate what 15 degrees is?

Comment: I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out what 15 degrees would be you need to use tan().

You are talking about a distance 1 unit away, so the height would just be $\tan(15^{\circ})*1$ and the mark 2/3 of the way up would be $\tan(30^{\circ})*1$

You can further verify that $\tan(45^{\circ})*1$ is the full 1 unit up.

These values are approximately 0.268, 0.577, 1

[image]

Comment: So for 15 degrees, I would have: [1 0 0.268]?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One last question. For 15 degrees above [101], would it be:

[tan(60) 0 1]

Comment: or [tan(30) 0 1]

Comment: It would be tan(60).  but [1 0 tan(60)] to keep in line with the other ones(which you probably knew).

Comment: That doesnt make sense to me. tan(60) = 1.732050807568878

This means that I would have: [1.7 0 1] but the x-component should be going to 0 before it hits the peak at [001]

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  I'll add an image of what I'm doing to my answer.